# how to deploy nextjs project in hostinger

Tags: next.js

does anyone know how to deploy a nextjs project in hostinger shared host , i'm stuck here.

the hosting provider has hpanel instead of cpanel, and you don't have any option to install nodejs.

i'm disappointed, i have just subscribed for 1 year. now i don't know what to do.

i have tried to put the built folder `.next` in the public_html folder and change the permission to `755` but nothing , the page displays

> 403 Forbidden "Access to this resource on the server is denied!"

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are other files visible in your public_html file? Assuming you just go for the built artefacts, your website would basically acts as a staticly served page.

Comment: Mohamed, were you able to solve it? I'm building a next.js project and want to use Hostinger as well. Which vps package did you choose, if any?

Comment: G6ix,  No, i have contacted the support, they said that nextjs is not supported in shared host, and if i want to deploy my nextjs i should use one of their vps plans

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Next.js cannot be deployed to Hostinger shared hosting, this can only be done using VPS. You can ask for a refund for the shared hosting you've already bought if it hasn't exceeded the 30days money-back guarantee. Then buy the VPS hosting plan and set things up on your own.

Comment: do you know how to set up the vps hosting? If so, would you mind helping me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you are deploying only static files exported from your NextJS build to your public_html directory, just make sure to have the following permissions set:

1. public_html - 755 ( ownership USER:USER )
2. Folders inside 755
3. Files inside 644

If you still experience a 403 error, I would recommend reaching their support for further help. If they lack support, then I would recommend looking for a managed hosting provider that can help you in such situations.

Comment: Thank you for your help , in fact i have contacted them , they said that nextjs is not supported in shared host, and if i want to deploy my nextjs i should use one of their vps plans.

Answer (score 1):

**Hostinger** supports the hosting of nextjs application but it will require the VPS(Virtual Private Server). Since, it is a node-server and supported by vps only. Although, if you wish to deploy application with just text you can do in shared web hosting, but no images optimization, API will work in shared web hosting.